# Joining sub-queries to get data for start and end provided dates optimization

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, join, sql-server-2008-r2

I'm using *SQL-Server 2008*.

I have to select stock of items at provided start date and stock of items at provided end date from 2 warehouses.

This is how I'm selecting `QuantityStock` for `@startDate`:

```
DECLARE @startDate DATE = '20160111'

SELECT *
FROM ( 
    SELECT SUM(QuantityStock) AS QuantityStockStart, Vendor, ItemNo, Company, [Date]
    FROM WarehouseA wha
    WHERE [Date] = (SELECT MAX([Date]) 
                    FROM WarehouseA wha2
                    WHERE wha.Vendor = wha2.Vendor
                          AND wha.ItemNo = wha2.ItemNo 
                          AND wha.Company= wha2.Company
                          AND [Date] <= @startDate)
    GROUP BY Vendor, ItemNo, Company, [Date]

    UNION ALL

    SELECT SUM(QuantityStock) AS QuantityStockStart, Vendor, ItemNo, Company, [Date]
    FROM WarehouseB whb
    WHERE [Date] = (SELECT MAX([Date]) 
                    FROM WarehouseB whb2
                    WHERE whb.Vendor = whb2.Vendor
                          AND whb.ItemNo = whb2.ItemNo 
                          AND whb.Company= whb2.Company
                          AND [Date] <= @startDate)
    GROUP BY Vendor, ItemNo, Company, [Date]
) stock_start
LEFT JOIN some_table st ON.....
```

As you see there are 2 similar queries, just selecting from different tables, for that I'm using `UNION ALL`

Also I'm using `[DATE] <= @startDate` that because not every day remaining stock is inserting, so for provided date `'20160111'` there can be no data, so need to select max date where remaining stock is inserted.

With query above a bit slowly, but working fine.

Problem is that I need to do the same with @endDate to get remaining stock for end date. Query is similar as above just instead of `@startDate` I need to use `@endDate`.

I've tried to use query above and `LEFT JOIN` similar query, just with `@endDate` instead of `@startDate` in following:

```
DECLARE @startDate DATE = '20160111',
        @endDate DATE = '20165112'

SELECT stock_start.*, stock_end.QuantityStockEnd
FROM ( 
    SELECT SUM(QuantityStock) AS QuantityStockStart, Vendor, ItemNo, Company, [Date]
    FROM WarehouseA wha
    WHERE [Date] = (SELECT MAX([Date]) 
                    FROM WarehouseA wha2
                    WHERE wha.Vendor = wha2.Vendor
                          AND wha.ItemNo = wha2.ItemNo 
                          AND wha.Company= wha2.Company
                          AND [Date] <= @startDate)
    GROUP BY Vendor, ItemNo, Company, [Date]

    UNION ALL

    SELECT SUM(QuantityStock) AS QuantityStock, Vendor, ItemNo, Company, [Date]
    FROM WarehouseB whb
    WHERE [Date] = (SELECT MAX([Date]) 
                    FROM WarehouseB whb2
                    WHERE whb.Vendor = whb2.Vendor
                          AND whb.ItemNo = whb2.ItemNo 
                          AND whb.Company= whb2.Company
                          AND [Date] <= @startDate)
    GROUP BY Vendor, ItemNo, Company, [Date]
) stock_start

LEFT JOIN ( 
    SELECT SUM(QuantityStock) AS QuantityStockEnd, Vendor, ItemNo, Company, [Date]
    FROM WarehouseA wha
    WHERE [Date] = (SELECT MAX([Date]) 
                    FROM WarehouseA wha2
                    WHERE wha.Vendor = wha2.Vendor
                          AND wha.ItemNo = wha2.ItemNo 
                          AND wha.Company= wha2.Company
                          AND [Date] <= @endDate)
    GROUP BY Vendor, ItemNo, Company, [Date]

    UNION ALL

    SELECT SUM(QuantityStock) AS QuantityStockEnd, Vendor, ItemNo, Company, [Date]
    FROM WarehouseB whb
    WHERE [Date] = (SELECT MAX([Date]) 
                    FROM WarehouseB whb2
                    WHERE whb.Vendor = whb2.Vendor
                          AND whb.ItemNo = whb2.ItemNo 
                          AND whb.Company= whb2.Company
                          AND [Date] <= @endDate)
    GROUP BY Vendor, ItemNo, Company, [Date]
) stock_end ON stock_start.Vendor = stock_end.Vendor AND stock_start.ItemNo = stock_end.ItemNo AND stock_start.Company = stock_end.Company
LEFT JOIN some_table st ON.....
```

In this way I got desired results, but Its execution time so high (about 10x longer than first query only with `@startDate`). Have you ideas how could I optimize It? It looks like there should be any other, simpler way, without repeating code...

So final results should be:

```
QuantityStockStart | Vendor | ItemNo | Company | [Date] | QuantityStockEnd
```

Comment: That looks strange. Why do you have two tables for two warehouses rather than only one table? Then these are two different warehoses you say, so how can there be duplicates? If warehouse a has 100 pieces of product X and warehouse B happens to have the same amount of X in stock, you want the total stock be shown as 100? Shouldn't that be two times 100 = 200?

Comment: In your SQL where you compare the date it says `WHERE [Date] = (SELECT MAX([Date]) FROM WarehouseB whb..`, but there is no closing parenthesis `)` ? So what does the `GROUP BY` do exactly? Shouldn't it close after `AND [Date] <= @endDate` ?

Comment: @ThorstenKettner It's not warehouses really, It's much difficult, I said warehouses for easier explanation. Idea is that necessary to use `UNION` with these 2 tables.

Comment: @BdR sorry, It was mistake while wrote sample data, fixed It.

Comment: Also shouldn't it be `AND [Date] >= @startDate` instead of `AND [Date] <= @startDate` ? Or are you trying to get the most recent dates before the @startdate and @enddate?

Comment: Its nonsense to use union. You will remive rows of identical itmes with identicsl stock on hand only and even then that is wrong. If you have 10 on hand in 2 places then you have 20 on hand, not 10.

Comment: @Used_By_Already no care about that, imagine that's `UNION ALL`, problem is not about `UNION` at all.

Comment: @BdR no, It's correct. I need to select stock for `@startDate`, for example for `2015-05-20`. But If stock information is not updated that day, It should select last day when It was updated (for example It could be updated in `2015-05-17`).

Comment: @Used_By_Already updated my query with `UNION ALL`, working correctly as with `UNION`, but how about my question now?

Comment: @ThorstenKettner updated my query with `UNION ALL`, working correctly as with `UNION`, but how about my question now?

Comment: I know the question isn't about the union; but would you prefer errors to be left undetected? + I was on phone when I made the comment, could not do any coding until on a keyboard once again (e.g. see suggestion below)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest use of the analytic function ROW_NUMBER() to locate the wanted source table rows. While there is no sample data to test against it is something of a guess but I think you may be able to do this:

```
SELECT
      whab.Vendor
    , whab.ItemNo
    , whab.Company
    , MIN(CASE WHEN whab.start_rn = 1 THEN whab.[Date] END)        start_dt
    , SUM(CASE WHEN whab.start_rn = 1 THEN whab.QuantityStock END) qty_at_start
    , MAX(CASE WHEN whab.end_rn = 1 THEN whab.[Date] END)          end_dt
    , SUM(CASE WHEN whab.end_rn = 1 THEN whab.QuantityStock END)   qty_at_end
FROM (
      SELECT
            Vendor
          , ItemNo
          , Company
          , [Date]
          , QuantityStock
          , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Vendor, ItemNo, Company
                  ORDER BY CASE WHEN [Date] <= @startDate THEN 1 ELSE 2 END, [Date] DESC) AS start_rn
          , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Vendor, ItemNo, Company
                  ORDER BY CASE WHEN [Date] <= @endDate THEN 1 ELSE 2 END, [Date] DESC)   AS end_rn
      FROM WarehouseA

      UNION ALL

            SELECT
                  Vendor
                , ItemNo
                , Company
                , [Date]
                , QuantityStock
                , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Vendor, ItemNo, Company
                        ORDER BY CASE WHEN [Date] <= @startDate THEN 1 ELSE 2 END, [Date] DESC) AS start_rn
                , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Vendor, ItemNo, Company
                        ORDER BY CASE WHEN [Date] <= @endDate THEN 1 ELSE 2 END, [Date] DESC)   AS end_rn
            FROM WarehouseB
) whab
WHERE whab.start_rn = 1
      OR whab.end_rn = 1
GROUP BY
      whab.Vendor
    , whab.ItemNo
    , whab.Company
```

Comment: please note that changes were made to the sql (i.e. please refresh) sorry

Comment: Thanks. please take care when choosing to use UNION instead of UNION ALL when performing subsequent aggregations - rarely would UNION be correct. Also look for ways to minimize the number of times you use any table, almost invariably that helps with performance. and... of course row_number() is a very cool tool to remember :)

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the subquery that follows `WHERE [Date]=` but keeping the where conditions from that subquery. Change `[Date]` to `MAX([Date])` and remove `[Date]` from the `GROUP BY` in the query that used to use the removed subquery.